# PowerApps Filter Dropdown A if Value Found in Dropdown B

Tags: filtering, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have 2 Dropdown controls, `AvailableSeats` and `BookedSeats`, both containing one Text value of `SeatName`.

I want to hide rows in `AvailableSeats` that are simply present *(not selected)* in `BookedSeats`.

How can this be implemented? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "found in BookedSeats" - as in selected in the `BookedSeats` dropdown or simply present as values in the dropdown?

Comment: @SamNseir simply present as values in the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Not(... in ...)` in your filter.

For example:

```
Filter(
  AvailableSeats,
  Not(SeatName in BookedSeats.SeatName )
)
```